# Laptop internal microphone not working (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Tags: microphone

I've been trying to make my laptop's internal microphone work.The sound card is: HDA Intel PCH. The laptop is an Acer Swift 3 SF315-52. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the brand and model of your notebook? This will make it more likely that someone may know of a solution.

Comment: Sure, I've included it.